# therubyracer Segmentation fault in rails 3.1.0.RC4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have no idea where to start debugging being a newbie. I got the code from someone else and is trying to set it up. I run the server and see a part of the page and the server stopped. Please help! Thanks in advance. Here is the trace:

```
aMe$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.0.rc4 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2011-07-07 10:01:46] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-07-07 10:01:46] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2010-12-25) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]
[2011-07-07 10:01:46] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1113 port=3000


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-07 10:01:47 -0500
  Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  Statistic Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `statistics`.* FROM `statistics` WHERE `statistics`.`key` = 'total_hours' LIMIT 1
   (2.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `people` WHERE (employee = 1 AND alumni = 0)
  Statistic Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `statistics`.* FROM `statistics` WHERE `statistics`.`key` = 'total_projects' LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `people` WHERE (employee = 1 AND alumni = 0)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `statistics`.* FROM `statistics` WHERE `statistics`.`key` = 'total_hours' LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `statistics`.* FROM `statistics` WHERE `statistics`.`key` = 'total_projects' LIMIT 1
Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (424.2ms)
Rendered layouts/_global_header.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 681ms (Views: 659.9ms | ActiveRecord: 20.9ms | Sphinx: 0.0ms)
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/therubyracer-0.9.2/lib/v8/context.rb:17: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25 revision 30365) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]

-- control frame ----------
c:0082 p:---- s:0483 b:0483 l:000482 d:000482 CFUNC  :New
c:0081 p:0140 s:0480 b:0480 l:000479 d:000479 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/therubyracer-0.9.2/lib/v8/context.rb:17
c:0080 p:---- s:0473 b:0473 l:000472 d:000472 FINISH
c:0079 p:---- s:0471 b:0471 l:000470 d:000470 CFUNC  :new
c:0078 p:0026 s:0468 b:0468 l:000467 d:000467 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/execjs-1.0.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:5
c:0077 p:---- s:0464 b:0464 l:000463 d:000463 FINISH
c:0076 p:---- s:0462 b:0462 l:000461 d:000461 CFUNC  :new
c:0075 p:0019 s:0458 b:0458 l:000457 d:000457 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/execjs-1.0.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:77
c:0074 p:0019 s:0454 b:0454 l:000453 d:000453 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/execjs-1.0.0/lib/execjs.rb:29
c:0073 p:0038 s:0450 b:0450 l:000449 d:000449 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:31
c:0072 p:0107 s:0447 b:0447 l:000446 d:000446 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:57
c:0071 p:0045 s:0442 b:0442 l:000441 d:000441 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/tilt-1.3.2/lib/tilt/coffee.rb:46
c:0070 p:0042 s:0436 b:0436 l:000435 d:000435 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/tilt-1.3.2/lib/tilt/template.rb:76
c:0069 p:0039 s:0430 b:0430 l:000668 d:000ba0 BLOCK  /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/context.rb:107
c:0068 p:---- s:0425 b:0425 l:000424 d:000424 FINISH
c:0067 p:---- s:0423 b:0423 l:000422 d:000422 CFUNC  :each
c:0066 p:0360 s:0420 b:0420 l:000668 d:000668 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/context.rb:104
c:0065 p:0105 s:0407 b:0407 l:000406 d:000406 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:22
c:0064 p:---- s:0398 b:0398 l:000397 d:000397 FINISH
c:0063 p:---- s:0396 b:0396 l:000395 d:000395 CFUNC  :new
c:0062 p:0098 s:0389 b:0389 l:000388 d:000388 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/environment_index.rb:118
c:0061 p:0091 s:0382 b:0382 l:000381 d:000381 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/environment_index.rb:64
c:0060 p:0093 s:0375 b:0375 l:000374 d:000374 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/environment.rb:89
c:0059 p:0051 s:0368 b:0368 l:000359 d:000367 BLOCK  /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:96
c:0058 p:---- s:0365 b:0365 l:000364 d:000364 FINISH
c:0057 p:---- s:0363 b:0363 l:000362 d:000362 CFUNC  :each
c:0056 p:0033 s:0360 b:0360 l:000359 d:000359 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:92
c:0055 p:0222 s:0354 b:0354 l:000353 d:000353 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:31
c:0054 p:---- s:0345 b:0345 l:000344 d:000344 FINISH
c:0053 p:---- s:0343 b:0343 l:000342 d:000342 CFUNC  :new
c:0052 p:0098 s:0336 b:0336 l:000335 d:000335 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/environment_index.rb:118
c:0051 p:0089 s:0329 b:0329 l:000328 d:000328 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/environment_index.rb:100
c:0050 p:0175 s:0321 b:0318 l:000317 d:000317 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/environment_index.rb:72
c:0049 p:0093 s:0311 b:0311 l:000310 d:000310 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/environment.rb:89
c:0048 p:0173 s:0304 b:0304 l:000303 d:000303 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/server.rb:42
c:0047 p:0229 s:0293 b:0293 l:000292 d:000292 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-mount-0.8.1/lib/rack/mount/prefix.rb:26
c:0046 p:0127 s:0286 b:0286 l:000259 d:000285 BLOCK  /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-mount-0.8.1/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152
c:0045 p:0014 s:0279 b:0279 l:000265 d:000278 BLOCK  /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-mount-0.8.1/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93
c:0044 p:0099 s:0274 b:0274 l:000273 d:000273 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-mount-0.8.1/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:68
c:0043 p:0198 s:0266 b:0266 l:000265 d:000265 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-mount-0.8.1/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92
c:0042 p:0092 s:0260 b:0260 l:000259 d:000259 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-mount-0.8.1/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141
c:0041 p:0025 s:0254 b:0254 l:000253 d:000253 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:531
c:0040 p:0017 s:0250 b:0250 l:000249 d:000249 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/hoptoad_notifier-2.4.11/lib/hoptoad_notifier/rack.rb:27
c:0039 p:0014 s:0243 b:0243 l:000234 d:000242 BLOCK  /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/warden-1.0.4/lib/warden/manager.rb:35
c:0038 p:---- s:0241 b:0241 l:000240 d:000240 FINISH
c:0037 p:---- s:0239 b:0239 l:000238 d:000238 CFUNC  :catch
c:0036 p:0086 s:0235 b:0235 l:000234 d:000234 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/warden-1.0.4/lib/warden/manager.rb:34
c:0035 p:0015 s:0230 b:0230 l:000229 d:000229 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17
c:0034 p:0015 s:0223 b:0223 l:000222 d:000222 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-1.3.0/lib/rack/etag.rb:23
c:0033 p:0068 s:0215 b:0215 l:000214 d:000214 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-1.3.0/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25
c:0032 p:0093 s:0208 b:0208 l:000207 d:000207 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14
c:0031 p:0046 s:0201 b:0201 l:000200 d:000200 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21
c:0030 p:0054 s:0196 b:0196 l:000195 d:000195 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:243
c:0029 p:0031 s:0188 b:0188 l:000187 d:000187 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-1.3.0/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195
c:0028 p:0013 s:0180 b:0180 l:000179 d:000179 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-1.3.0/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190
c:0027 p:0020 s:0176 b:0176 l:000175 d:000175 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:321
c:0026 p:0064 s:0168 b:0168 l:000167 d:000167 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:54
c:0025 p:0029 s:0160 b:0160 l:000159 d:000159 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool
c:0024 p:0014 s:0152 b:0152 l:001560 d:000151 BLOCK  /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29
c:0023 p:0155 s:0150 b:0150 l:000149 d:000149 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392
c:0022 p:0024 s:0140 b:0140 l:000139 d:000139 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81
c:0021 p:0013 s:0134 b:0134 l:001560 d:001560 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28
c:0020 p:0027 s:0130 b:0130 l:000129 d:000129 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:68
c:0019 p:0015 s:0125 b:0125 l:000124 d:000124 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-1.3.0/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:102
c:0018 p:0049 s:0115 b:0115 l:000114 d:000114 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48
c:0017 p:0017 s:0111 b:0111 l:000110 d:000110 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47
c:0016 p:0027 s:0103 b:0103 l:000102 d:000102 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13
c:0015 p:0155 s:0099 b:0099 l:000098 d:000098 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-1.3.0/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24
c:0014 p:0032 s:0093 b:0093 l:000092 d:000092 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-1.3.0/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17
c:0013 p:0057 s:0084 b:0084 l:000083 d:000083 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72
c:0012 p:0068 s:0080 b:0080 l:000079 d:000079 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-1.3.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:34
c:0011 p:0124 s:0074 b:0074 l:000073 d:000073 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53
c:0010 p:0015 s:0068 b:0068 l:000067 d:000067 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/hoptoad_notifier-2.4.11/lib/hoptoad_notifier/user_informer.rb:12
c:0009 p:0032 s:0060 b:0060 l:000059 d:000059 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/engine.rb:438
c:0008 p:0015 s:0056 b:0056 l:000055 d:000055 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/rack/content_length.rb:16
c:0007 p:0015 s:0047 b:0047 l:000046 d:000046 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14
c:0006 p:0356 s:0042 b:0042 l:000041 d:000041 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-1.3.0/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59
c:0005 p:0257 s:0030 b:0030 l:000029 d:000029 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111
c:0004 p:0393 s:0020 b:0020 l:000019 d:000019 METHOD /Users/aMe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70
c:0003 p:0126 s:0009 b:0009 l:000778 d:000008 BLOCK  /Users/aMe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:---- s:0002 b:0002 l:000001 d:000001 TOP   
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/Users/aMe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-1.3.0/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/rack/content_length.rb:16:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/hoptoad_notifier-2.4.11/lib/hoptoad_notifier/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-1.3.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:34:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-1.3.0/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-1.3.0/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-1.3.0/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:102:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:68:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392:in `_run_call_callbacks'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:54:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:321:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-1.3.0/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-1.3.0/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195:in `context'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:243:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-1.3.0/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-1.3.0/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/warden-1.0.4/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/warden-1.0.4/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/warden-1.0.4/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/hoptoad_notifier-2.4.11/lib/hoptoad_notifier/rack.rb:27:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:531:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-mount-0.8.1/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-mount-0.8.1/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-mount-0.8.1/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:68:in `optimized_each'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-mount-0.8.1/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `block in recognize'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-mount-0.8.1/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `block in call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rack-mount-0.8.1/lib/rack/mount/prefix.rb:26:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/server.rb:42:in `call'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/environment.rb:89:in `find_asset'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/environment_index.rb:72:in `find_asset'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/environment_index.rb:100:in `find_asset_in_path'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/environment_index.rb:118:in `build_asset'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/environment_index.rb:118:in `new'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:31:in `initialize'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:92:in `compute_dependencies!'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:92:in `each'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:96:in `block in compute_dependencies!'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/environment.rb:89:in `find_asset'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/environment_index.rb:64:in `find_asset'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/environment_index.rb:118:in `build_asset'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/environment_index.rb:118:in `new'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:22:in `initialize'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/context.rb:104:in `evaluate'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/context.rb:104:in `each'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10/lib/sprockets/context.rb:107:in `block in evaluate'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/tilt-1.3.2/lib/tilt/template.rb:76:in `render'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/tilt-1.3.2/lib/tilt/coffee.rb:46:in `evaluate'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:57:in `compile'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:31:in `context'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/execjs-1.0.0/lib/execjs.rb:29:in `compile'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/execjs-1.0.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:77:in `compile'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/execjs-1.0.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:77:in `new'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/execjs-1.0.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:5:in `initialize'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/execjs-1.0.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:5:in `new'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/therubyracer-0.9.2/lib/v8/context.rb:17:in `initialize'
/Users/aMe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/therubyracer-0.9.2/lib/v8/context.rb:17:in `New'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap
aMe$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.1.0.rc4, 3.0.5, 3.0.3)
actionpack (3.1.0.rc4, 3.0.5, 3.0.3)
activemodel (3.1.0.rc4, 3.0.5, 3.0.3)
activerecord (3.1.0.rc4, 3.0.5, 3.0.3)
activeresource (3.1.0.rc4, 3.0.5, 3.0.3)
activesupport (3.1.0.rc4, 3.0.5, 3.0.3)
acts_as_list (0.1.2)
annotate-models (1.0.4)
arel (2.1.1, 2.0.9, 2.0.6)
autotest (4.4.6)
autotest-fsevent (0.2.4)
autotest-growl (0.2.9)
autotest-rails-pure (4.1.2)
bcrypt-ruby (2.1.4)
builder (3.0.0, 2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.10, 1.0.7)
cancan (1.6.5)
capistrano (2.6.0)
chunky_png (1.2.0)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.1.1)
compass (0.11.1, 0.10.6)
configuration (1.2.0)
devise (1.3.4)
diff-lcs (1.1.2)
erubis (2.7.0, 2.6.6)
execjs (1.0.0)
factory_girl (1.3.2)
factory_girl_rails (1.0)
faker (0.3.1)
fssm (0.2.7)
gravatar_image_tag (1.0.0.pre2)
gruff (0.3.6)
haml (3.0.25)
haml-rails (0.3.4)
has_scope (0.5.0)
heroku (1.20.1, 1.16.2)
highline (1.6.2)
hike (1.1.0)
hoptoad_notifier (2.4.11)
hpricot (0.8.4)
i18n (0.6.0, 0.5.0)
inherited_resources (1.2.2)
jquery-rails (1.0.9)
json (1.5.1)
json_pure (1.4.6)
kaminari (0.12.4)
launchy (0.3.7)
libv8 (3.3.10.2 x86_64-darwin-10)
magic_encoding (0.0.2)
mail (2.3.0, 2.2.15, 2.2.14)
meta_where (1.0.4)
mime-types (1.16)
mocha (0.9.12)
multi_json (1.0.3)
mysql2 (0.3.2)
net-scp (1.0.4)
net-sftp (2.0.5)
net-ssh (2.1.4)
net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
nifty-generators (0.4.6)
nokogiri (1.4.4)
orm_adapter (0.0.5)
paperclip (2.3.11)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.3.0, 1.2.2, 1.2.1)
rack-cache (1.0.2)
rack-mount (0.8.1, 0.6.13)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.0, 0.5.7)
rails (3.1.0.rc4, 3.0.5, 3.0.3)
railties (3.1.0.rc4, 3.0.5, 3.0.3)
rake (0.9.2, 0.8.7)
rdoc (3.6.1)
responders (0.6.4)
rest-client (1.6.1)
riddle (1.3.3)
rmagick (2.9.1)
rspec (2.5.0, 2.0.1)
rspec-core (2.5.1, 2.0.1)
rspec-expectations (2.5.0, 2.0.1)
rspec-mocks (2.5.0, 2.0.1)
rspec-rails (2.5.0, 2.0.1)
ruby_parser (2.0.6)
rubygems-update (1.4.2)
sass (3.1.2)
sequel (3.20.0)
sexp_processor (3.0.5)
sinatra (1.0)
spork (0.8.4)
sprite-factory (1.2.0)
sprockets (2.0.0.beta.10)
sqlite3 (1.3.3)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.2)
sys-uname (0.8.5)
taps (0.3.23)
therubyracer (0.9.2)
thor (0.14.6)
thumbs_up (0.4.1)
tilt (1.3.2)
treetop (1.4.9)
tzinfo (0.3.28, 0.3.24, 0.3.23)
uglifier (0.5.4)
warden (1.0.4)
webrat (0.7.1)
will_paginate (3.0.pre2)
ZenTest (4.4.2)
```

Comment: Problem solved after switching to ruby 1.8.7! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using older versions of execjs and therubyracer. Versions of execjs and therubyracer prior to 1.1.3 and 0.9.2 respectively did not properly lock V8. These crashes have since been fixed. I would recommend upgrading both of these gems to their latest versions.

Comment: Good idea.  Ruby 1.8.7 is now the older poorer cousin of 1.9.2 (or 1.9.3) that many folks rely on (in production).

Answer (score 0):

Did you install a javascript runtime framework? TheRubyRacer needs that to work? For my ubuntu VPS I had to do that manually. Mac OS X ships with this.

Comment: I'm on OSX. So I guess I'm good. But how do I know if I did install?

Comment: See here: https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs it looks like something called "Apple JavaScriptCore - Included with Mac OS X" should be included by default. I had no problems on Mac OS X but I had NodeJS installed as well.

Comment: So i've installed that gem too, doesn't help. Thanks anyway.